`yb_is_database_colocated` is missing after upgrading YugabyteDB cluster to 2.18.1.0
We found today the issue, that the function yb_is_database_colocated() is missing after an upgrade to 2.18.1.0.
select yb_is_database_colocated();
[Code: 0, SQL State: 42883]  ERROR: function yb_is_database_colocated() does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 83  [Script position: 83 - 110]

This breaks pg_dump. Is there any known workaround for this?
(delete data is until now not really an option, except downgrading, but we are not sure on this).

How did you perform an upgrade?
This function definition changes a little since version 2.18.
You have to run yb-admin upgrade_ysql to upgrade its definition.
Generally, you always want to run the command above after every upgrade to pick up our new features.
It’s also stated in the upgrade docs: https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/manage/upgrade-deployment/
